# ViewControllers not resizing for 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7, autolayout

I'm really struggling with this one. I searched this issue all over but no one seems to experience exactly the same problem.

So I have this ios7 project, which should run on both 4 and 3.5 inch devices. 
On 4 inch, everything is fine, but on 3.5 inch view controllers have frames height of 568

If i log the UIScreen bounds in AppDelegate, it returns correctly 480. But if i create UIViewController and add it as rootViewController to NavigationController, its height is 568.
(NavigationController has too a proper height of 480)

First, I thought it may be because of XIB, so i created blank UIViewController just by
[[UIViewController alloc] init], but it still has height of 568.

This is driving me crazy, because my other project works fine this way and viewcontrollers are resized automatically.

I checked i have a proper starting images defined in images.xcassets, and i tried XIB both with and without autolayout.

Only one thing helped, if i turn simulated metrics in xib to NONE or 3.5 inch, but then i dont get fullcreen on 4 inch. And having multiple xib for both screens is not solution for me.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If you use auto layout, check if you set proper constraint to make the view auto resize according to the screen size else check if you set the right autoResizingMask.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I was able to resolve issue when i create view controller programatically (i had to clear derived data, and clean product) but now I need to get the autolayout in XIB to work properly. I was looking into the constraints, but it seems to me i can define constraints only for child views, but not for main view controller's view. How do you set the constraints for autoresizing according to the screen?

Comment: this guide will help you to support both ios 6 and ios 7 , https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html

Comment: agree, this problem is infuriating.  in a somewhat similar situation, this saved the day .. -  (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews { // horrible fix, to make it position properly on all (most?? many??) devices! self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0); }

Answer (score 1):

I was currently facing this problem as i am using the autoLayouts but now I have resolved this issue using nib. So i want to share it with you.

If you are making a viewController through nib. Then you should make sure that  "Resize View From NIB"  is checked . After doing this you will get the frame height of the view w.r.t  screen bounds. ( in 3.5 inch screen it will be  480 and in 4 inch it will be 568).

[image]

Comment: What is the version of the view in the xib document? My is "iOS 7 and Later". I can not see this option.

Comment: I m currently using xCode 5.1.1.And my project was in Storyboarding. 
Do you use storyboard or simple xib???

Comment: I do not use story boards in my project.
My problem was inherited from auto layout malfunction. I had not properly defined the constraints for a scroll view's content and this issue was propagating through the constraint relationships up to the main controller. 

Also because I create my main window in code (I need to parametrize delegate class in the main that is why I do not use xib for main window). The main window should be set like this:

    UIWindow* window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    window.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; etc

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me except it was the other way around - the app ran on the 4 inch with a 3.5 inch screen.

The trick is your launch images. Make sure that your R4 image is actually for the 4 inch and the @2X Image is for the 3.5 inch.

Comment: Exactly the same as for bigger devices. The LaunchImage determines which sizes to display. Here you have Apple's official Guideline with regard sizes of all devices and images/icons: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 1):

YOU get the size in wrong timing.

The initialized size is from NIB, 
SO you need get the adjusted size in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` (lower version in `-viewDidAppear`)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Turns out that I had a embeded segue and that the original container view was hard coded to 568:

[Here](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but something to look out for.